# Android: Footer layout gravity is not respected in my RecyclerView

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

This is the layout of my RecyclerView:

```
<com.xxx.mobile.ui.widget.list.PagingRecyclerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/background"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:paddingTop="16dp" />
```

I use this layout to add like footer in my RecyclerView:

**loading_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/loading_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
    style="?android:progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It works correctly, BUT the progressBar is not center horizontally...

Ps: my RecyclerView uses LinearLayout at the initialisation:

```
myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'v updated my request. Thanks Yvette